# Check jstree search result

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

Can I check if jsTree serach yields some results?

for example, can I do something like that:

```
var searchResult = $('#myTree').jstree('search', 'keyword');
if(searchResult.haveResults){
   Do something...
};
```

Comment: Finally I found some solution:

        var searchResult = $('#myTree').jstree('search', 'keyword');
    if($(searchResult).find('.jstree-search').length == 0){
       Do something...
    };

.jstree-search is the css class which stick to results nodes.

Yair

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found some solution:

```
var searchResult = $('#myTree').jstree('search', 'keyword');
if ($(searchResult).find('.jstree-search').length == 0) {
   //Do something...
};
```

.jstree-search is the css class which stick to results nodes.

Comment: I used a similar approach with `var count = $(".jstree-container-ul li .jstree-search").length;`